# Best way to implement random numbers into a table via a button?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a table right now that, upon clicking a button, will populate the table with some arbitrary values.

What I would like for it to do instead, is populate the table with random numbers, upon each click of the button.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Not sure if this is really what you want.  But based on your description of what you want.. -> `$col.text(Math.trunc(Math.random() * 100))`,  would fill those cells with random number between 0 and 99.

Comment: hey that's actually what i'm looking for. I'm new to java script, where exactly would I place this line of code?

Comment: inside your `$.each(fields, function(index, field)`

Comment: Got it to work, thanks!